# Asterisk queue: going to failover destination after 3 retries?

Tags: asterisk, asteriskami

I am working on Asterisk 12.8.0.
I want to know if it's possible to configure a queue in order if a caller has called 3 times 3 differents agents and these didn't answer him, the caller is going to failover destination?

For example :

```
-- Executing [1@ext-queues:40] Queue("SIP/531004-0000001f", "1,t,,,60,,,,,") in new stack
== Using SIP RTP TOS bits 184
== Using SIP RTP CoS mark 5
-- Called SIP/531002
-- SIP/531002-00000020 is ringing
-- SIP/531002-00000020 is ringing
-- Nobody picked up in 10000 ms
-- Auto-Pausing Queue Member SIP/531002 in all queues since they failed to answer on queue 1.
== Using SIP RTP TOS bits 184
== Using SIP RTP CoS mark 5
-- Called SIP/531005
-- SIP/531005-00000021 is ringing
-- SIP/531005-00000021 is ringing
-- Nobody picked up in 10000 ms
-- Auto-Pausing Queue Member SIP/531005 in all queues since they failed to answer on queue 1.
== Using SIP RTP TOS bits 184
== Using SIP RTP CoS mark 5
-- Called SIP/531007
-- SIP/531007-00000022 is ringing
-- SIP/531007-00000022 is ringing
-- Nobody picked up in 10000 ms
-- Auto-Pausing Queue Member SIP/531007 in all queues since they failed to answer on queue 1.
```

After that, I want the caller leaving the queue if possible, how can I make this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the timeout of the Queue dialplan application:

```
[Syntax]
Queue(queuename[,options[,URL[,announceoverride[,timeout[,AGI[,macro[,gosub[,rule[,position]]]]]]]]])
```

Dialplan execution will continue on the next step/priority. You already have 60 seconds configured.
I guess you're using FreePBX configuration, it's probably not that easy to change (add a next step/priority) dialplan contexts in that solution. [ext-queues] is possibly a built in.

Comment: Yes, I'm using FreePBX to configure my queues, it's easier. So, even it's not possible, the caller can still be led to the failover destination if nobody can answer him in the queue.

Comment: Using FreePBX will limit the possibilities of dialplan configuration a bit. What you can set in FreePBX is easier, but waht you can't is a pain in the ass then.